# Datepicker - prevent String from being converted to date

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

in my uib-datepicker I´m filling the parameter uib-datepicker-popup with the pattern '2. Hj' + 'yyyy' . The 'H' will be converted to 12. How to prevent that?
I tried '/H', but it didn´t work.
Thanks, I already tried to google, but didn´t find the right answer.

Input '2. Hj' + 'yyyy'
desired output: '2. Hj 2018'

Comment: Please provide the input and your desired output in the question.

Comment: Try to put the static characters in `[]`, i.e. pattern should be `'[2. Hj]' + 'yyyy'`

Comment: Thansk, but it didn´t work. output in this case is (e.g.):  [2. 12j] 2018

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. You have to use '2. \'H\'j' . Then the H is not formatted